# Groovy:remove all namespace from xml

Tags: xml, groovy, apache-nifi

I  want  to  romeve  namespaces  from my  xml  response(now  i  am  working inside  nifi  environment,so  i  have  to use   groovy  utilities)
here  is  my  code ,  but it   throws FlowfFileHandlingException,  what  should 
 i  change  to make  this  code  work?:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import groovy.lang.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.lang.String;
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil



def flowFile=session.get();
 String removeXmlStringNamespaceAndPreamble(String xmlString) {
  return xmlString.replaceAll("(<\\?[^<]*\\?>)?", ""). 
  replaceAll("xmlns.*?(\"|\').*?(\"|\')", "") 
  .replaceAll("(<)(\\w+:)(.*?>)", "${1}${3}") 
  .replaceAll("(</)(\\w+:)(.*?>)", "${1}${3}"); 
  }

 def text = ''
   session.read(flowFile, {inputStream ->
   text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
   } as InputStreamCallback)

//text=removeXmlStringNamespaceAndPreamble(text);
log.error(removeXmlStringNamespaceAndPreamble(text));
  def root = new XmlSlurper( false, false ).parse( text );
  String outxml = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( root );   
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {outputStream ->
   outputStream.write(outxml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
   }  as OutputStreamCallback)
session.transfer(flowFile,REL_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy remove part of xml using namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975471/groovy-remove-part-of-xml-using-namespace)

Comment: I  have  seen  this  post before  i  posted my  question  here  but  it  doesn't  fit  my example

Comment: How would your sample xml look like?Because you can remove namespace without using groovy in NiFi

Comment: <GetPatientTreatmentTeamResponse xmlns="urn:Custom-com:Common.2014.Services.Patient">
     <GetPatientTreatmentTeamResult xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <CSN>422332</CSN>
        <PatientIDs>
           <PatientID>
              <ID>23424</ID>
              <IDType>type</IDType>
           </PatientID>
           <PatientID>
              <ID>45335</ID>
              <IDType>typt</IDType>
           </PatientID>
        </PatientIDs>
</GetPatientTreatmentTeamResult>
</GetPatientTreatmentTeamResponse>

Comment: it  looks  like  this   but  here  isn't  full  version  i  have  much  more namespaces